# QML: Load images in GridView

Tags: image, performance, qt, qml

I am a QML beginner ans want to load some pictures in my application. With a `FileDialog` I choose the folder containing around 1000 images.

Then, I want to load them in a `GridView`. A `SwipeView` helps to split the images to 40 images/screen. So the `SwipeView` has 25 pages.

Now how can I load the images without waiting 1 hour until they are load?

Here is my code:

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Controls 2.1
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1
import Qt.labs.folderlistmodel 1.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Controls 2.1
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.1
import QtQml.Models 2.1


Window{
    visible: true
    width: 1000
    height: 600

    FolderListModel{
        id: lm
        showDirs: false
    }

    FileDialog {
        id: fileDialog
        selectFolder: true
        title: "Please choose a folder"
        folder: shortcuts.home
        onAccepted: {
            lm.folder = fileUrl+"/"
        }
        onRejected: {
            console.log("Canceled")
            Qt.quit()
        }
        Component.onCompleted: visible = true
    }

    SwipeView {
        width: 800
        height: 500
        clip: true
        currentIndex: 0

        Repeater {
            model: Math.ceil(lm.count / 40)
            delegate: gridView
        }
    }
    Component{
        id: gridView

        GridView{
            interactive: false
            width: 800
            height: 500
            property int viewIndex: index
            model: DelegateModel {
                model: lm
                groups: DelegateModelGroup { name: 'filter' }
                Component.onCompleted: {
                    for (var i = viewIndex * 40; i < lm.count && i < (viewIndex * 40) + 40; i++) {
                        items.setGroups(i, 1, ['items', 'filter'])
                    }
                }

                filterOnGroup: 'filter'

                delegate: Image {
                    width: 80
                    height: 120
                    source: lm.folder+fileName
                    asynchronous: true
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

If anyone can help me, I would be happy.

Thanks and regards,

Eddie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are loading all the 1000 images, not only for the current page.

As a quick solution, I would suggest you to define a `filterOnGroup` as `'filter'` only if it is `GridView` on the current page, like:

```
// note: `swipeViewId` is an id of the SwipeView
filterOnGroup: swipeViewId.currentIndex == index ? 'filter' : ''
```

Another way is to use `Loader` as a delegate for `SwipeView` and set its `sourceComponent` to `gridView` if it is current or to null otherwise.

```
Repeater {
    model: Math.ceil(lm.count / 40)
    delegate: Loader {
        sourceComponent: SwipeView.isCurrentItem ? gridView : null
        onLoaded: {
            item.viewIndex = index
        }
    }
}
```

Also, you may play with [sourceSize](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-image.html#sourceSize-prop) property of the `Image` if the actual images are larger then its preview (80x120 in your example)

Comment: Tahnk you a lor for your help! I am almost there, I have the problem, that on all pages of the SwipeView I get the same 40 images? Can you help me?

Comment: Sure, but it would be easier if you show the code you have now.